# struts2 ajax with checkbox

Tags: ajax, jsp, struts2

i am not able to bring my ajax called checkbox in correct position using div with id(`<div id="reverse" style="position:absolute; left:500px; top:379px;"></div>`)how can i bring them with one row with three columns.if i am using this code i am not able to position it after the selectbox named modNameCheck.instead it is coming at the side of select box

```
<s:form action="queueform1.action" name="queueform1" method="post" >

   <s:select label="Flow Name" list="flowNameList" name="flowNameCheck" >
       <s:iterator status="stat" value="flowNameList">
       </s:iterator>   
   </s:select> 
   <s:textfield name="formnam" value="" label="Form Name"/>
   <s:textfield name="formhead"  value="" label="Form Heading"/>
   <s:checkbox  name="initiator" fieldValue="yes" 
                label="Click here if initiator"/>
   <s:textfield name="compldays"  value="" label="Complete day"/>
   <s:select label="Department" list="modNameList" 
             name="modNameCheck" id="detail" onchange="chk3()">
       <s:iterator status="stat" value="modNameList">
       </s:iterator>   
   </s:select>
   <div id="reverse" style="position:absolute; left:500px; top:379px;">
   </div>
   <s:textfield  name="getcheckid" value=""/>
   <s:submit value="Save" align="center" />     

</s:form>
```

my ajax code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">        
    chk3=function()
    {
       //alert("hai!!");
       //$("#hide").hide();
       var vals2=$("#detail").val();
       //alert(vals2);
       $.post("userQueueAjaxForm.jsp",{modName:vals2},function getattname(data)
       {
        $("#reverse").html(data);

       });                       
    }    
</script>
```

my ajax called checkbox is

```
while(rs.next())
{ 

   %>    

   <input type="checkbox" id='attributeNameCheck[<%=i%>]' name="checkname"  
      onclick="attributeformcreation('queueform1','attributeNameCheck[<%=i%>]');"
      value="<%=rs.getString(1)%>"><%=rs.getString(2)%>

   <%i++;%>

   <%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Scriptlets (`<%`, `<%=`...).

Scriptlets are bad.

I strongly suggest to take a look on how to refactor this in a pure Struts2 way, without Scriptlets... there are plenty of examples out there ;)

That said, your problem is not related to Struts2 nor Ajax, it is simple css:

you are just lacking the

```
display: inline-block;
```

into your div (that, being a block-level element, feeds a new line by default).

Then:

```
<div id="reverse" style="display: inline-block;"></div>
```

should work as expected.

Then play with margins / padding of the div to get the desired result.